# BIRT/JasperReports с Intellij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, jasperreports, birt

Для использования BIRT/JasperReports с Eclipse есть плагины, а можно ли использовать их с IntelliJ IDEA? Поиск в гугле никаких вменяемых ответов на этот вопрос не даёт, и всё, что я нашла по этому поводу в англоязычном SO - [этот вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32177299/birt-reports-and-intellij) (что наводит на неутешительные мысли). Может, у кого-нибудь есть опыт использования этих генераторов отчётов?..